# feature hashing on image features (ORB) - scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, feature-extraction

I am trying to train an SVM using ORB features for an image. Each ORB point has 32 integer values showing the intensity for the keypoint. The number of keypoints is variable, so I am looking into using feature hashing.

```
            img = cv2.imread(img_name,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            if img is None: continue
            gray = cv2.resize(img,(256,256))
            smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)
            kps = orb.detect(smooth,None)
            kp, descs = orb.compute(smooth, kps)
            #print des.shape
            desc_dict = {}
            for i,desc in enumerate(descs):
                desc_dict[i] = desc
```

here is how the desc_dict looks like

```
{0: array([ 88, 143, 234, 183,  23, 248, 107,  50, 113, 205,  78,   2, 111,
       227, 146, 116,  48, 230, 189, 203,   8, 216, 173, 109, 247, 103,
       232, 129,  39, 231,  86, 110], dtype=uint8), 
1: array([ 71, 246, 250, 192, 114, 152, 191,  31,  43, 199,  90, 239, 221,
       206, 222,  16,  55, 253,  53,  21, 195, 148, 182, 194,  62,  30,
        47, 236, 140, 178, 131, 245], dtype=uint8), 
2: array([190, 205, 100, 238, 221,  82, 222, 230,   1,   6, 248, 131, 105,
       125,  61, 128, 223, 243, 151, 227, 108, 170,  72, 239, 115, 127,
       142, 147, 119, 255, 252,  14], dtype=uint8),
            :
            :
          <n>
```

I am confused about how to pass this to the `FeatureHasher`. Should I convert the array into a catenated string? Sorry I am a newbie to this, and could use some guidance.